# How can I manage a daemon service inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, init

I'm running `avahi-daemon` inside of a Docker container. Currently I'm starting this by simply running it from the compose file. Is there a way to start it in a "managed" fashion, so it automatically restarts if it fails? Currently, due to the lack of an init process if it fails it becomes defunct and a replacement cannot be started.

Answer (score 1):

It [looks like](https://linux.die.net/man/8/avahi-daemon) you can just run it without a `--daemonize` option; then it will be a foreground process that can be the main container process.  You can then use a Docker [restart policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/#use-a-restart-policy) to restart the container if it fails.

A minimal Dockerfile could look like:

```bash
FROM ubuntu:20.04
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      avahi-daemon
CMD ["avahi-daemon", "--no-chroot"]
```

And the corresponding Compose setup:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  avahi-daemon:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.avahi-daemon
    restart: on-failure
```

Comment: Ah that's interesting thanks, however I don't want to restart the container if Avahi falls over, just the process.

Comment: Why not?  The container isn't really much beyond a wrapper around the single process it runs.

Comment: Because this container isn't running a single process—it's running a webserver and we're using Avahi to broadcast a hostname